# How do I get to the desert?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

I know I need the Angler Key from the desert, but beyond that, I am stumped. I haven't even figured out how to get to the desert, much less the key.

Ulira has told me the desert is in the southeast of the island, but I can't really figure out how to get there.

Comment: I should play the game again so I can start answering your questions.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Desert is in the South-west corner, as is documented in this [wiki article](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Yarna_Desert). There is a [detailed article](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda04-links-awakening-walkthrough-04.php#C4_1) as to how exactly to get into the desert. The basic steps are:

1. Try to find Marin. Start in Mabe Village.
2. Head to Toronbo Shores. There after some searching you will find Marin.
3. Head to the desert, and she will sing to the Walrus. That will cause the Walrus to move out of the way, allowing you access to the Desert.

Comment: It's important to note that for Marin to appear, you *must* visit Animal Village and trade for the pineapple. If you don't have it, she won't be on the beach until you do. (In fact, this post is actually kind of obtuse and needlessly vague. If I wasn't so busy I'd fix it :/)

Comment: This is missing a lot of details - I had better luck using the linked article, even though it was also confusing.

Comment: Here's the big picture. The place you are looking for is on the bottom right. http://www.zeldawiki.org/images/c/c0/Koholint_Island.png

Answer (score 2):

You have to travel [through the Animal Village](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/links-awakening-walkthrough/anglers-tunnel/#c4_1). Immediately southwest of the Castle and Seashell Mansion, there is a shrub/bush to remove, which reveals a staircase:

[image: image of staircase via https://www.zeldadungeon.net/links-awakening-walkthrough/anglers-tunnel/#c4_1]

Should be straightforward from there:

> The animals in town mention needing Marin to wake the walrus blocking the path. Marin is waiting by the ocean, where the story began.

---

Here is a screenshot of the Game Boy version, [per zeldadungeon.net's walkthrough](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/links-awakening-walkthrough/anglers-tunnel-game-boy-color/);

[image: zeldadungeon.net GBC screenshot]