# How can I find Marin?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening-2019

I just opened the entrance to the last dungeon and realized I don't have the first Ocarina song, so I tried to find Marin:

- Last time I saw it, it was right before entering the desert.
- Not found on Mabe village, nobody in her house.
- Not found on Animal village, I've never seen her singing there.

After this I found her again on the broken bridge, near the last dungeon, but could not get the missing Ocarina song.

I saw [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55291/how-do-i-get-to-the-desert/55294#55294) question and realized I did not have the Pineapple before entering the desert, if that could mean something...

How can I get the first Ocarina song I'm missing?

Comment: How did you manage to get to the last dungeon without the first ocarina song? That song is required to access the fourth dungeon, and the treasure from the fourth dungeon allows access to the fifth. Which means if you don't get the song, you can't progress at all. Did you glitch the game or something?

Comment: @MageXy, what do you mean you need Marin's song to open dungeon 4 (Angler's Tunnel)? Marin sings to the walrus herself to get into the desert. I've literally played it in one place other than the egg and that was just for a secret seashell.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm misremembering. I thought when she sings to the walrus, the song gets unlocked at that time.

Comment: @MageXy No, you don't even need the ocarina there, Marin sings the song to you afterwards, normally in Animal Village, and you learn it

Comment: Oh that's right. There were a handful of NPCs that mentioned the Dream Shrine before I woke the walrus, so I got the ocarina before I went to find Marin at the beach. That's probably why I got confused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you refer to dungeon 8 "Turtle Rock" with saying you opened the last dungeon, you should just finish the dungeon. 
For me she was back in Mabe village after finishing the dungeon.

I wanted to talk to her to say my last good bye before waking the Windfish, so i am sure about it.

---

The Pineapple is for the trade sequence of the game, which does contribute to the story as well but is not needed until the very end.

The last Item you get from the trade sequence will help you find the code you need to traverse the windfish egg.

Comment: Already finished the trade sequence, ill try to find her again after finishing the dungeon. Thanks!

Comment: It's just north of the Golden Gate bridge!  I'm here right now!